# Using sonarqube to monitor continuous delivery

Tags: sonarqube, devops, continuous-delivery

I'm wondering if anybody has considered/tried using the SonarQube system to monitor not just the health of the code, but the health of a continuous delivery pipeline as well.

It seems like it would be well suited for this sort of thing with its drill downs, extensible metrics and integrations with various test types (unit, integration, system) etc.

For example: a plugin that warns when the build time of a particular phase is getting too high, or how many defects a particular defect has caught in the last few months.

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube platform is focused on intrinsic code quality, and is not an all-purpose metric history display. Attempting to use it as such would really be a misuse.

If you want warnings when a job in the pipeline takes too long, I would consider a timeout on the job instead.

Comment: The DevOps movement advocates for the notion of "Infrastructure as Code", meaning that the infrastructure (and the system that deploys it) is in fact an intrinsic part of a software development project itself.  In the same way that tests, though they are not "payload code" are in fact part of the project software, and are part of the quality ecosystem of the product.  As such, does it not make sense to include analysis of the deployment pipeline as part of the "intrinsic code quality" of a product?